# Intermittent transaction deadlock upon ROLLBACK

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, transactions, asyncpg

We have a database which we're writing >10,000 rows to across a half dozen tables every ~5 minutes. The writes are done in a single transaction block created using the sqlalchemy `AsyncEngine` class's `.begin()` context manager from a python backend. Prior to this monolithic transaction, several `SELECT` queries are made to gather old data for number crunching on the python side. These queries are run in transactionless blocks using the sqlalchemy `AsyncEngine` class's `.connect()` context manager. Usually, this goes off without a hitch, however, occasionally the database will deadlock and the culprits are usually one of the `INSERT` queries and a `ROLLBACK TO __asyncpg_savepoint_xxx__` query. The table which the stuck `INSERT` query operates on is not always the same. This happened again recently and I captured some of the state surrounding the event:

Live Queries:

```
PID     Runtime     State                    Query
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
804471  00:46:35    idle in transaction      ROLLBACK TO __asyncpg_savepoint_711__;

701711  00:19:04    idle in transaction      RELEASE SAVEPOINT __asyncpg_savepoint_7a9__;

805473  00:13:29    active                   INSERT INTO market_metadata (market_id, event_id, market_type, name) VALUES ($1::integer, $2::integer, $3::jsonb, $4::varchar)
```

pg_locks table:

```
   locktype    | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid   |       mode       | granted | fastpath 
---------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+---------+----------
 relation      |    16642 |    16691 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 15/32397           | 805473 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16673 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 15/32397           | 805473 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16689 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 15/32397           | 805473 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16683 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 15/32397           | 805473 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16675 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 15/32397           | 805473 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 15/32397   |               |         |       |          | 15/32397           | 805473 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    12143 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 17/10677           | 807678 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 17/10677   |               |         |       |          | 17/10677           | 807678 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    17132 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    27191 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    17131 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16689 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16683 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16683 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16694 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16680 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16701 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    17129 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    17123 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16673 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16712 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16696 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16696 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16675 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16642 |    16675 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 10/18469   |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 18/5481    |               |         |       |          | 18/5481            | 804471 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61050 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61041 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61048 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61094 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61037 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61043 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61032 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61090 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61076 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 relation      |    16642 |    17131 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61086 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61071 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61060 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61034 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61049 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61114 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61054 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61118 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61095 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61111 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61093 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61058 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61033 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61096 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61115 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61121 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61042 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61057 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61040 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61110 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 relation      |    16642 |    17123 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61030 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61059 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 relation      |    16642 |    27191 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61038 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61089 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61070 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61112 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61117 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61056 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61073 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61084 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61077 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61092 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61098 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61039 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61075 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61066 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61044 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61113 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61067 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61061 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61068 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61105 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61119 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61053 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61083 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61074 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61030 |         |       |          | 15/32397           | 805473 | ShareLock        | f       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61104 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61123 |         |       |          | 15/32397           | 805473 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61035 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61088 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61055 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61046 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61099 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61101 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61102 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61120 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 relation      |    16642 |    17129 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | RowShareLock     | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61108 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61062 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61036 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61106 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61079 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61091 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61103 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61100 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61078 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61047 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61097 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61064 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61109 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61116 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61031 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61045 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61069 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61085 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61072 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61065 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61080 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61087 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61051 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61052 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61063 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |         61107 |         |       |          | 10/18469           | 701711 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
```

For context, these `INSERT` batches usually take 5-10 seconds when everything goes right, and as previously mentioned, these runs happen every ~5 minutes so there *should* be plenty of time for any `ROLLBACK` operation to complete successfully before a new batch of `INSERT`s arrive.

What strikes me as odd is the sheer number of `transactionid` exclusive locks acquired by `701711` for what should be a single transaction. Also, `ROLLBACK TO __asyncpg_savepoint_711__;` had all the locks it asked for so I see no reason why it should hang indefinitely, especially when the deadlock seems to be between the other 2 processes this time.

I'm not an expert in databases by any stretch and don't know what best practices are surrounding high-volume use cases; could it be the size of the transaction? Maybe the fact it's a multi-table transaction? If anyone could help shed some light on what could be going wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it and if additional information is required, I'll edit the post when this inevitably happens again.

EDIT:
Python excerpt where the `INSERT`s take place:

```py
async with self._db_engine.begin() as transaction:
    run_id = await create_run(transaction, self._time_of_run)

    if ids_newly_created:
        newly_created_snapshots = generator_over(
            ids_newly_created, self._market_id_to_current_snapshot
        )
        await self._bulk_insert_into_market_metadata(transaction, newly_created_snapshots)

    if ids_changed := ids_changed | ids_newly_created | ids_changed_from_inactive:
        changed_snapshots = generator_over(ids_changed, self._market_id_to_current_snapshot)
        market_snapshot_creation_data = await self._bulk_insert_into_market_snapshot(
            transaction, changed_snapshots
        )

        for row in market_snapshot_creation_data:
            market_id, snapshot_id = row["market_id"], row["id"]
            current_snapshot = self._market_id_to_current_snapshot[market_id]
            run_market_snapshot_rows.append(
                {
                    "snapshot_id": snapshot_id,
                    "overround": current_snapshot.overround,
                    "volume": current_snapshot.volume,
                }
            )

    if run_market_snapshot_rows:
        for row in run_market_snapshot_rows:
            row["run_id"] = run_id
        await self._bulk_insert_into_run_market_snapshot(transaction, run_market_snapshot_rows)

    if tree_and_metadata_records["metadata"]:
        await self._bulk_insert_into_event_metadata(
            transaction, tree_and_metadata_records["metadata"]
        )

    if tree_and_metadata_records["tree"]:
        await self._bulk_insert_into_event_tree(transaction, tree_and_metadata_records["tree"])
```

One of the _bulk_insert_into functions (they're all very similar and serve to limit the number of args per INSERT to 32767 which appears to be asyncpg's limit):

```py
async def _bulk_insert_into_market_metadata(
    self, transaction: AsyncConnection, snapshots: SizedGenerator[MarketSnapshot]
) -> None:
    extract_colums_from_snapshot = partial(extract_table_columns, market_metadata_tbl)
    rows_to_insert = map(extract_colums_from_snapshot, snapshots)
    chunked_rows = chunk_insert_data(market_metadata_tbl, SizedGenerator(rows_to_insert, len(snapshots)))
    for rows in chunked_rows:
        await transaction.execute(market_metadata_tbl.insert(), list(rows))
```

Comment: It would help to see the Python code, or at least a [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Anonymous Unfortunately I don't have an MRE since in testing I couldn't reproduce it at all. It really is just a loose cannon. I added the python code responsible for the INSERTs

Comment: A `ROLLBACK` can never deadlock. Please look at the PostgreSQL log to get details and add the relevant parts to the question.